# Is it possible to make a excel-window run in the background?

Tags: excel, barcode-scanner, setfocus

I'm starting a project at work where the workers are supposed to get a scanner to scan barcodes on the vares that they use. Optimaly we would have a system supporting this, but we don't.

My thought is to be able to have excel running in the background on the computer they use to several other things, like reading newspapers and looking up todays weather etc. My understading of scanners is that they work just like a keyboard when connected to a computer, problems may then arise if someone is scanning barcodes, and another one is reading the newspaper in internet explorer, maybe the barcodes pops-up as a number in the URL(?), when it really should go to a specific cell in excel.

*My question: Is it possible to make a scanner always return its values(scanned barcodes) to excel, EVENTHOUGH the computer may be used to something else at the same time?*

Thanks for every thought and comment!
Have a nice weekend!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think Excel would be the best solution to achieve this. It may be possible to achieve by linking to the scanner API and leveraging external libraries to listen for the scanner port etc. However, these kind of applications best be installed as system services e.g. Windows Service or as any other background application in .NET, Java, Python whatever. Excel is not the first choice technology to do these sort of things. Excel, however, can well be used for outputing this data.

What is more, honestly, the solution and feasibility will depend on the scanner API or driver.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I guess you're right. I've settled for the mobile app quickmark
(http://www.quickmark.com.tw/En/basic/index.asp)

for now, which basically does what I want. It has this option to do "bulk scanning" and then export the scanned codes to a txt/excel-file.

I was hoping that the same program was compatible with an actual handheld industrial scanner, but it seems like smartphones are killing the market! :)